# jquery input array to slug dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, slug

I am working on a CMS system "tries" to support multilingual natively.

I have form fields like

```
<input name="title[en]" type="text">
```

and using a slugger plugin which works successfully when I select the input field:

```
$("input[name=title\\[en\\]]").stringToSlug({getPut: "input[name=url\\[en\\]]"});
```

Question is: My `en,fr,de,es` values comes from db. How can make a `foreach` loop to tell jquery it should write the same line for multiple language like:

```
$("input[name=title\\[en\\]]").stringToSlug({getPut: "input[name=url\\[en\\]]"});
$("input[name=title\\[fr\\]]").stringToSlug({getPut: "input[name=url\\[fr\\]]"});
$("input[name=title\\[de\\]]").stringToSlug({getPut: "input[name=url\\[de\\]]"});
$("input[name=title\\[es\\]]").stringToSlug({getPut: "input[name=url\\[es\\]]"});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only involves a simple refactoring technique: make a loop. If you create an array of the languages you want to use, you can use the jQuery [`.each` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to acheive this.

```
$.each(["en", "fr", "de", "es"], function(index, lang) {
  $("input[name=title\\[" + lang + "\\]]").stringToSlug({getPut: "input[name=url\\[" + lang + "\\]]"}); 
}
```

If you are concerned about performance and don't want the overhead involved in the `.each` method, you can use a traditional `for` loop instead:

```
var langs = ["en", "fr", "de", "es"];
for(var i = 0; i < langs.length; i++) {
  var lang = langs[i];
  $("input[name=title\\[" + lang + "\\]]").stringToSlug({getPut: "input[name=url\\[" + lang + "\\]]"}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use something like this:

```
$.each(['en','fr','de','es'], function (i, lang) {
  $("input[name=title\\["+lang+"\\]]").stringToSlug({getPut: "input[name=url\\["+lang+"\\]]"});
}
```